# Find the closest array location that has a specific value in a 2d array (optimized)

Tags: arrays

Its a bit had to phrase what I'm looking for, but basically, I'm trying to take a location in a 2D array and find the closest spot in the array to that location that has a negative value. (no diagonals, no pythag therorem. Think of distance as the number of spaces a rook would have to traverse to get from one location to another on a chess board). Here's an example.

lets say I have an array like this:

GenericArrayName = [

[-1, -1, 0, 1, 1],

[0, -1, 1, 1, 0],

[1, 0, 0, -1, -1]

]

and I have location 1, 4 in the array. (Array locations start at zero).

How would i go about finding the closest negative value in the array to GenericArrayName[1][4]?

I can think of a couple of solutions, but the problem is, I need to find the closest negative number to **every location in the array not equal to 0** (I want to find the closest positive value for the negatives in the array, but that will be easy to implement after I can do that with just the negative numbers). The reason I bring this up, is that my actual array differs in size depending on a certain setting. With my current tests the array is 43 by 24 in size, but I have no reason to put an upper limit on the size of the array (besides the amount of time it takes) so the solutions I can think of would be unimaginably slow. I don't need something as optimized as Fast InvSqrt(), but I do need it to take less than a second to run whatever solution once, preferrably less than half a second.

I'm not looking for a ctrl-c + ctrl-v solution, but would rather a solution that i can figure out how to code myself. I'm not a veteran, so I may ask for clarification, as this problem seems like it would/could have a difficult answer.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "closest"? According to which metric? Do you mean the distance in a two dimensional space (square root of x^2 + y^2) or are rows and columns not weighted equally for your needs? And a second point to clarify: Your specific example GenericArrayName does have only entries in the range 0-2 in the first array-index and 0-4 in the second index. So I don't see how your "location 4,1" makes sense. Do you mean [1][4]? And why in the next line [5][2]?? Is this supposed to be the size of the array? But that's 3 for the first index and 5 for the second...

Comment: My apologies for not being specific enough. when I said closest, I was thinking of the distance as how many spaces at minimum a rook would have to traverse to reach the location if the array was a chessboard. I've looked at arrays and always seen the first part as the horizontal, and the second as the verticle, so I saw the dimensions of the array as 5 spaces (0-4) by 3 spaces (0-2) not the other way around. [5][2] was a mistake. I realised that arrays start at zero while I was fixing a mispell in the title, and forgot the change the second time I refrenced the location to the correct numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the distance. And about the array index position: it's certainly a matter of convention or interpretation, which index you regard as vertical and which as horizontal. However, what is not so much a matter of interpretation (because it is the same in all programming languages that I know, but please correct me if you know other examples) is which index corresponds to the outer array (the first) and which index to the inner arrays (the second). Therefore I still think it has to be [1][4].

Comment: You can still make [1][4] consistent with your preferred view of the first index being the horizontal one, by just writing the same array as a list of column vectors, if you know what I mean (transposed notation of the same matrix). But I know that this issue has nothing to do with your actual question, so I won't insist on this one. At least I understand now what you mean.

Comment: back to the actual question: As I understand now, your metric is simply distance=dx+dy . Which algorithms have you thought of so far? I guess in order to calculate the closest negative entry to [4][1] one would start looking into all entries with distance 1. As soon as you find a negative entry, you're done. Then look into all entries of distance two. Again, if you find a negative entry, you're done. In order to walk through all entries of a certain distance, you probably need [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of the distance you have reached. Agree so far?

Comment: Depending on the size of the array, that could get pretty slow, especially if I did it for every location in the array that isn't 0. I've consulted my dad, and he said that one way I might be able to do it, is to go right to left top to bottom and whenever I find a negative number, tell set the spaces below and to the right of that space that the closest negative is the aformentioned location (I want to location of the closest, I don't actually care about the exact distance). Then pull that info from the spaces it is in down and to the right untill I find another negative number.

Comment: Then, I do the same thing again, but from the bottom left to the top right, but only pull the info if the place it is pulling to doesn't already have a closer stored location.

Comment: Something else, the solution being slow wouldn't really matter, if the array wasn't input based. Everything in the array starts at 0, and can be changed while the program is running via user input, so i can't just find the closest negative once when the prgram is first run.

Comment: And as for [4][1] vs [1][4], so long as i initialize and access the array in consistent methods, it doesn't really matter if at look at is as if it has been rotated 90 degrees. I do agree that most languages (as far as I know) have the outer array as the as the first access paramiter and the inner arrays as the second access paramiter.

Comment: sorry for not replying anymore. I'm in vacations until end of October, have rarely internet nor time. When I'm back I'll read your comments more carefully, but I hope somebody else can help you in the meantime.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Me and my dad sat down and figured it out for a bit, and it seems we settled on something pretty close to what Sebastian suggested in the comments, although not exactly. I was under the wrong impression of how long a solution like Sebastian suggested might take to run, so I brushed it off. Turns out I was quite wrong. The solution we settled on was pretty simple in concept. Effectively, we have four diffrent functions, up, down, left, and right. when called, the up and down functions would call themselves recursively until they reached the end of the array, and the left and right functions would call up and down, before calling left/right respectively. The functions would be called whenever a nested for loop reached a positive or negative number in  the array. inputted to the functions is the location of the positive/negative number that was found (stx/sty) (the starting point), if the number is positive or negative (posneg), their current position (curx/cury), the length and height of the array (enx/eny), and the distance from the starting point (dist) (with the distance metric of dx + dy). Then the function would check if their location (by which I mean curx and cury as was passed into the function earlier) is the location of another item that is of the same positive/negative polarity as themselves, and if it is, they return 0 (i use return to stop the function). If the space is 0 or is a diffrent positive negative polarity, then they check if the distance value stored in the array for the current space exists, or that it is smaller than the distance value that was passed into the function. if either is true, it writes the starting point x and y into the corrosponding parts of the array, and the distance value, before reccurring itself with the nessicary changes to the curx/cury and dist values. Here's my code.

```
{ // Closest in array
enum depmean{
    item = 0, // I use this to store what type of thing is in the location. The positive/negative is just what team it is on.
    posix = 1, // The x location (in the array) of the closest positive number.
    posiy = 2, // The y location (in the array) of the closest positive number
    negix = 3, // The x location (in the array) of the closest negative number.
    negiy = 4, // The y location (in the array) of the closest negative number.
    posdist = 5, // The distance to the closest positive number (stored in the array) using the metric dx + dy
    negdist = 6 // The distance to the closest negative number (stored in the array) using the metric dx + dy
}
function closestinarray(){
    var i1 = array_length(global.WorldArray)
    var j1 = array_length(global.WorldArray[0])
    for(var i = 0; i < i1; ++i){ // Nested for loop to navigate the array
        for(var j = 0; j < j1; ++j){ // ++ is the same as += 1
            var abc = global.WorldArray[i][j][depmean.item]
            if(abc != 0){
                if(abc > 0){
                    passto(i, j, i1, j1, 1) // The 1 indicates a positive number has been found, which appears as the variable posneg in the function
                } else {
                    passto(i, j, i1, j1, -1) // The -1 indicates a negative number has been found, which appears as the variable posneg in the function
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function passto(stx, sty, enx, eny, posneg){
    // posneg specifies if the array location at [stx][sty] is positive or negative, so the code can know if they need to edit posix, posiy and posdist or negix, negiy, and negdist.
    // stx/sty is the "starting x/y" or the location that I will be passing to other array locations to say "this is the closest pos/neg to your array location"
    // enx/eny is just where the code needs to stop before it tries to access array locations that don't exist
    if(posneg = 1){
        global.WorldArray[stx][sty][depmean.posdist] = 0
    } else {
        global.WorldArray[stx][sty][depmean.negdist] = 0
    }
    var dist = 1
    if(sty > 0){ // Checking if the up function will be outside of the array
        up(stx, sty, enx, eny, stx, sty - 1, dist, posneg)
    }
    if(sty < eny){ // Checking if the down function will be outside of the array
        down(stx, sty, enx, eny, stx, sty + 1, dist, posneg)
    }
    if(stx > 0){ // Checking if the left function will be outside of the array
        left(stx, sty, enx, eny, stx - 1, sty, dist, posneg)
    }
    if(stx < enx){ // Checking if the right function will be outside of the array
        right(stx, sty, enx, eny, stx + 1, sty, dist, posneg)
    }
}
function up(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury, dist, posneg){
    // curx/cury is the "current x/y" of the array that the code is working on/modifying
    if(spreadclosecoords(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury, dist, posneg)){ // This same code works for all of the functions (up down left right), so I just put it in a function.
        if(cury > 0){ // Checking if the up function will be outside of the array
            up(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury - 1, dist + 1, posneg)
        }
    }
}
function down(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury, dist, posneg){
    // curx/cury is the "current x/y" of the array that the code is working on/modifying
    if(spreadclosecoords(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury, dist, posneg)){ // This same code works for all of the functions (up down left right), so I just put it in a function.
        if(cury < eny){ // Checking if the down function will be outside of the array
            down(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury + 1, dist + 1, posneg)
        }
    }
}
function left(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury, dist, posneg){
    // curx/cury is the "current x/y" of the array that the code is working on/modifying
    if(spreadclosecoords(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury, dist, posneg)){ // This same code works for all of the functions (up down left right), so I just put it in a function.
        if(cury > 0){ // Checking if the up function will be outside of the array
            up(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury - 1, dist + 1, posneg)
        }
        if(cury < eny){ // Checking if the down function will be outside of the array
            down(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury + 1, dist + 1, posneg)
        }
        if(curx > 0){ // Checking if the left function will be outside of the array
            left(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx - 1, cury, dist + 1, posneg)
        }
    }
}
function right(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury, dist, posneg){
    // curx/cury is the "current x/y" of the array that the code is working on/modifying
    if(spreadclosecoords(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury, dist, posneg)){ // This same code works for all of the functions (up down left right), so I just put it in a function.
        if(cury > 0){ // Checking if the up function will be outside of the array
            up(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury - 1, dist + 1, posneg)
        }
        if(cury < eny){ // Checking if the down function will be outside of the array
            down(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury + 1, dist + 1, posneg)
        }
        if(curx < enx){ // Checking if the  right function will be outside of the array
            right(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx + 1, cury, dist + 1, posneg)
        }
    }
}
function spreadclosecoords(stx, sty, enx, eny, curx, cury, dist, posneg){
    var curv = global.WorldArray[curx][cury][depmean.item]
    if(posneg == 1){
        if(curv > 0){ // Checking if the item on the current location is a positive number, because if it is, it will be closer to any farther locations on the array, past it, and there is no point in running it again.
            return 0
        }
        var curd = global.WorldArray[curx][cury][depmean.posdist]
        if(curd == noone or curd > dist){ // Checking if the distance value stored in the currrent location of the array is == noone (I initalize the array to noone, meaning that is it is noone, it doesn't have a value yet.) or if the stored location is greater than the distance that the function has had passed into it.
            global.WorldArray[curx][cury][depmean.posix] = stx
            global.WorldArray[curx][cury][depmean.posiy] = sty
            global.WorldArray[curx][cury][depmean.posdist] = dist
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    } else {
        if(curv < 0){ // Checking if the item on the current location is a negative number, because if it is, it will be closer to any farther locations on the array, past it, and there is no point in running it again.
            return 0
        }
        var curd = global.WorldArray[curx][cury][depmean.negdist]
        if(curd == noone or curd > dist){ // Checking if the distance value stored in the currrent location of the array is == noone (I initalize the array to noone, meaning that is it is noone, it doesn't have a value yet.) or if the stored location is greater than the distance that the function has had passed into it.
            global.WorldArray[curx][cury][depmean.negix] = stx
            global.WorldArray[curx][cury][depmean.negiy] = sty
            global.WorldArray[curx][cury][depmean.negdist] = dist
            
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    return 1
}
}
```

The array_length() function is a function built into the software I use (GameMaker Studio 2 (gms1 was used by Toby Fox to make Undertale)). The function simply returns the length of the specified dimention of the array starting at one (so an array with locations 0, 1, 2 would return 3 when put in the function).

This solution runs fast enought that on my really bad laptop, I can see no stutter even if I run it every frame. Seeing as I only need to run it every once in a while, that's amazing.

If you see any bugs or you are having the problem yourself and need some clarification, please tell me! I'd like to maybe help out someone who needs this for themselves.

Comment: I'm glad you found yourself a solution for your needs and share it here. It's a pity that you got downvotes without reasoning, but I guess it's because there are a lot of variables, where not all of them might be relevant, so it's hard to follow. You noted this yourself for the variable `powerlvl`. In general it's a good idea to put on SO only a minimal working example and not the complete code that you're using yourself. In particular I guess you could remove the `lookfor != noone` case. 
And BTW you haven't specified the language. Looks like Javascript?

Comment: Some questions for clarification.
You use some function `array_length()` which I see nowhere defined. Is it the total number of entries of the array, so the length of the first array-index times the length of the second array index?

Furthermore, in your code comments you have explanations of all the `depmean`-variables,  but the meaning of the arguments of your functions (like `curx`, `stx` and so on) seems nowhere explained. "cur" for "current" maybe?

Comment: My apologies. I'm using a language called GML (game maker language) in a program called game maker studio 2 (Toby Fox used gms1 for undertale). Its most comparable to java from what I've heard in terms of how it runs. curx is the current "X" in the array (its a 2d array so i can make connections like that even if they dont technically make sense.) and stx is the x origin of the array location that I am telling other array locations to refrence when looking for the "closest" positive/negative value. same goes for cury and sty, just with y coords

Comment: array_length is a predefined function that gms2 has, which tells you the length of a specific dimension of an array starting at 1, so running array_length on an array with locations 0, 1, 2 would return 3. specifying the dimention of the array to check is as simple as adding brackets and specifying the dimention. i.e. array_length(testarray[1]) would return the number of entries in the second dimention at the location [1] in the first dimention of the array. (I am explaining this poorly) I will go back and make the nessicary changes to my answer. Wish I knew why my question got downvoted.

Comment: I mentioned the powerlvl variable so that people knew that I was already using that array location, and as such the relevant depmean variables would be refrenceing an array location of one greater than expected. I will go and change that.

Comment: Okay, I have hopefully removed all unessicary variables and added comments explaining the variables that I hadn't explained before. Please tell me if I missed something. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, that helps already a lot!, though I'm still confused. As a minor remark, in your function `passto()` in the first conditional `if(posneg = 1)` it should probably be a double "==", right? Next, in contrast to your example `GenericArrayName` of your question (2 array indices), the `WorldArray` seems to have 3 indeces. Is it true that for every value of `item` you consider a separate 2d-Array? But why is then the `item` sometimes used as the first index (in the second line of `closestinarray` and in other places as the last index?

Comment: Ah, I guess I better understand depmean now. It is supposed to be the possible values of the 3rd index in which you store the extra information about the previously 2d array, right? But why is then the `depmean.item` once used as the first index (in the second line of `closestinarray`)?

Comment: I guess in the second line of `closestinarray` you should explicitly use the index `0`. The array_length would be the same for all possible values of the first index i, so it is legitimate to choose i=0 to get the second dimension. But using `depmean.item` as index is misleading (even though it's value is 0 and thus the same). Furthermore it seems to me as if your nested `for` -loops don't reach the last value. Because you subtracted already 1 in the definition of `i1`and `j1` but in the loop you are using `<i1` and `<j1` instead of `<=`. So you never reach the maximum allowed index...

Comment: Maybe you should add to your answer, how you actually would apply your algorithm to the example of your question. As I understand it, you first need to turn the 2d-Array into a 3d-Array. I'm not familiar with the syntax of GML, but it should be something where you replace each element by an array containing the former element at position 0. E.g. in javascript it would be `WorldArray = GenericArrayName.map(row=>row.map(el=>[el]))`.
Next you run your function `closestinarray()`. And finally you read off the result for the example-entry [1][4]: 
`[0,1,3,1,1,1,3]`. Do you get the same result?

Comment: Now the result says: 0 is the 2d-Array-value at this position (correct), (1,3) are the coordinates of the closest positive value with distance 1 (correct) and (1,1) should be the closest negative value with distance 3. However, this last part is not true, as there is also a negative value at position (2,4) with distance only 1. I'm not sure where the error is, but it might be related to the indices in the for loops not running to their upper limits...

Comment: in fact, when the loops run to the upper limit, one obtains at position [1][4] the result `[ 0, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1 ]`. So the closest positive is now at (0,4) (different but still correct) and the closest negative at (2,4), both with distance 1. This seems correct to me. Your approach is interesting, but it is still hard to follow the code. I guess you could reduce the number of arguments (dist e.g. is redundant, enx eny also don't need to be passed around and maybe there are other steps to make the code more readable. But nevertheless nice job!

Comment: This is probably necroposting, but thank you for taking the time to comment all this stuff! I'll try to find the time to put in the changes you've mentioned. The language I'm using is weird and can tell when it should consider = as an assignment or a boolean operator, but I should make sure to change that to == anyway, because it's still good practice

Comment: Never mind, I prefer receiving a late response to getting no response. You're welcome, and thanks for the "=" - clarification!

Comment: since it has been  a year, I don't really understand why I used depmean.item instead of just 0. Defenitly a poor choice that makes it harder to read the code. You are correct in assuming that my code would miss the final indicies of the array. I assume I meant to use `i/j <= i1/j1` in the for loops, but forgot to. I was originally using this code to run a funny little battle simulator for a school project about Sun Tzu's the Art of War, and I needed the characters to automatically move on the grid to the nearest enemy troop.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the OP's own answer, I'm posting here the approach that I suggested in my first comments, namely starting at the current position and looping over increasing distance, looking for a negative entry at these fixed distances and return, as soon as the negative entry is found. I'm not saying that it is in any way more efficient than the OP's own answer, but it might be useful if one is not necessarily interested in the answer for all entries at once, but only for a particular point. The code is also a bit shorter. I restricted myself to finding the closest negative entry to a given position (e.g. the position [1][4] of the question). The closest positives are of course analogue. As I'm not familiar with GML, I did the implementation in Javascript, but I think it's similar enough to be easily transferable to the former:

```
// returns the coordinates [i,j] of the closest negative entry to [x,y] within the array "arr"
function getClosestNeg(arr, x, y) {
    var xlength = arr.length;
    var ylength = arr[0].length;
    for (var dist = 0; dist < Math.max(xlength - 1, ylength - 1); dist++) { // maximal distance is one less than the dimension
        for (var i = Math.max(0, x - dist); i <= Math.min(xlength - 1, x + dist); i++) {
            // distance is fixed via Math.abs(x-i) + Math.abs(y-j) == dist
            // for dist > 0 two cases, j < y and j > y or explicitly j == (y + Math.abs(x-i) - dist) and j == (y -Math.abs(x-i) + dist)
            var j = y + Math.abs(x-i) - dist;
            if (j >= 0 && j < ylength && arr[i][j] < 0) {

                return [i, j];
            }

            j = y - Math.abs(x-i) + dist;
            if (dist > 0 && j >= 0 && j < ylength && arr[i][j] < 0) {

                return [i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    return null; // when the array doesn't contain any negative entries
}
```

Now calling `getClosestNeg(GenericArrayName, 1, 4)` yields the expected position `[2,4]`. Of course, in this approach if you want to get all the closest positions, you naively need to iterate through the complete 2d-array and make the call for every position. Depending on the distribution of the negatives, this can be far from optimal, as one doesn't take into account the information already obtained. However, when the negatives are reasonably frequent (so that each search terminates for small distances), this naive approach might not perform much worse than more sophisticated ones. In any case, getting all results in this way and collecting them in yet another array can be obtained via the following function:

```
function getAllClosest(arr) {
    var result = [];

    var xlength = arr.length;
    var ylength = arr[0].length;

    for (var x = 0; x < xlength; x++) {
        result[x] = [];
        for (var y = 0; y < ylength; y++) {
            result[x][y] = getClosestNeg(arr, x, y);

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

A situation where this approach would be very bad, is if the 2d array contains very few, or in the worst case even no single negative. Then each call for each entry needs to search up to the maximum possible distance. I guess that in such a situation a solution along the ideas of the OP's answer should be much more efficient.

**Remark:** If I'm not mistaken, the OP question is just a particular case of a [nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Linear_search) and thus has already lots of theoretical background and algorithms